# Lubuntu 17.04 - Multiple displays not recognized [HDMI]

Tags: lubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, monitor

I have Lubuntu 17.04 installed.  I have it connected via HDMI to a monitor, and I am trying to get it to mirror.

1. My monitor display settings does not pick up another monitor.
2. I tried installing `xrandr` and a few other GUIs but all that does is further show how the OS is not detecting the monitor.
3. The cables are plugged in properly and work fine otherwise.
4. I have tried rebooting, unplugging and replugging in cables.

Please, any advice would be great, I like the OS and would hate to have to switch because I can't use HDMI output.

Also, I have Intel graphics, and according to some basic Google searching and running commands, I already have Intel support drivers installed but have no way of accessing any options or controls.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this.

I plugged the HDMI into my TV and it worked automatically.  Then I unplugged it and plugged it back to the original monitor that it was not recognizing and now it works.